# Python mySQL Update, Working but not updating table

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, mysql-connector-python

I have a python script which needs to update a mysql database, I have so far:

```
dbb = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", 
       user="user", 
       passwd="pass", 
       db="database") 
try:
   curb = dbb.cursor()
   curb.execute ("UPDATE RadioGroups SET CurrentState=1 WHERE RadioID=11")
   print "Row(s) were updated :" +  str(curb.rowcount)
   curb.close()
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
   print "query failed<br/>"
   print e
```

The script prints `Row(s) were updated :` with the correct number of rows which have a `RadioID` of 11. If I change the `RadioID` to another number not present in the table it will say `Row(s) were updated :0`. However the database doesn't actually update. The `CurrentState` field just stays the same. If I copy and past the SQL statement in to PHPMyAdmin it works fine.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

use

```
dbb.commit()
```

after

`curb.execute ("UPDATE RadioGroups SET CurrentState=1 WHERE RadioID=11")`

to commit all the changes that you 'loaded' into the mysql server

Answer (score 28):

As the @Lazykiddy pointed out, you have to commit your changes after you load them into the mysql.

You could also use this approach to enable the auto commit setting, just after the MySQL connection initialization:

```
dbb.autocommit(True)
```

Then, it will automatically commit the changes you made during your code execution.

Comment: This begs the question though, will this function make the database commit happen after every query kind, even SELECT that does not alter the table in any way?

Answer (score 13):

the two answers are correct. However, you can also do this:

```
dbb = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", 
   user="user", 
   passwd="pass", 
   db="database",
   autocommit=True)
```

add **autocommit=True**