# Error when controlling mysql with python class

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to update a mysql database using class system but cannot get the update part to work. It was all ok the old way but I wanted to use the class system with exception error control. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. At the moment for this script I am just trying to send the variable Boileron to the database column office.

```
import MySQLdb

class DBSolar:
    conn = None

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.conn = MySQLdb.connect("192.xxx.x.x", "exxxxx", "Oxxxx", "hxxxx")
        except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
            print (e)
            self.conn = None
        return self.conn

    def query(self, sql):
        try:
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
        except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
            self.connect()
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
        return cursor

    def update(self, task):
        boilerState = task
        try:
            sql = "UPDATE dashboard SET office = ? WHERE id = 1", (boilerState)
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
        except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
            self.connect()
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
        return

while 1:

    BoilerOn = 1
    print BoilerOn

    dbSolar = DBSolar()
    connSolar = dbSolar.connect()

    if connSolar:
        dbSolar.update(BoilerOn)
```

Below is the error report from putty console

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test2.py", line 47, in <module>
     dbSolar.update(BoilerOn)
   File "test2.py", line 29, in update
     cursor.execute(sql)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 223, in execute
     self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, m)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorvalue
 TypeError: query() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this working changed the update to the following

```
def update(self, task):
    try:
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("UPDATE dashboard SET office = %s WHERE id = 1", [task])
        self.conn.commit()
    except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
        print (e)
        self.connect()
        #cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        #cursor.execute(sql)
        #self.connect.commit()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [MySQL Developer document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)

> Since by default Connector/Python turns autocommit off, and MySQL 5.5 and higher uses transactional InnoDB tables by default, it is necessary to commit your changes using the connection's commit() method. You could also roll back using the rollback() method.

You need to add `self.conn.commit()` after `cursor.execute(sql)` to commit all the changes.

Or turn on the `autocommit` which is described in [Python mySQL Update, Working but not updating table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271907/python-mysql-update-working-but-not-updating-table)

Comment: I assume you mean like this  cursor.execute(sql)
                           self.conn.commit()                                        which I have tried but it still comes up with an error. I will update my original post with the error

Answer (score 0):

Your `sql` creata a tuple, but `cursor.execute(statement, params)` is expecting a *string* for the `statement` and either a *tuple* or a *dictionary* for `params`.

For MySQL UPDATE, you also need to commit the execution.

Therefore try:

```
self.conn.cursor.execute("UPDATE dashboard SET office = %s WHERE id = 1", (str(task), ))
self.conn.commit()
```

I would suggest you read the ['MySQL Connector/Python Development Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) better understating of using MySQL in python.

Comment: This has stopped the tuple error but it is not updating the office row in the database. i will have to do some more research on this

Comment: Run a direct SQL on your MySQL to see whether you have the same problem